# Referencing a listing and getting two question marks

Tags: formatting, listings, labels, texshop

I'm using TexShop 4.69 and I'm using `lstlistings`. But now after inserting my 3rd `lstlisting`, I can't get an adequate reference number. I'm receiving now two “??" in my text. Can somebody please give me a tip?

```
See Listing \ref{lst:codejson}.

 \begin{lstlisting}
[caption={JSON Format},captionpos=b,label=lst:codejson,language=bash]

[{
"id":0,
"category":"Category",
"chapter":"Chapter",
"requester":"Requester",
"version":"Version",
},
...
]
 \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: you always need to run latex wice to get cross references to resolve, hav you run it again?

Comment: Yes, I did but than I removed , language=bash after this it worked. Don't know why but now I'm happy :-) Thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 1):

The bracket introducing the options to `lstlistings` must be in the same line as `\begin{lstlisting}`.

With your code I get

[image]

and you see that the options are treated as part of the listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

See Listing \ref{lst:codejson}.

\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={JSON Format},
  captionpos=b,
  label=lst:codejson,
language=bash
]
[{
"id":0,
"category":"Category",
"chapter":"Chapter",
"requester":"Requester",
"version":"Version",
},
...
]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]